# missing parameter type for simple expression

Tags: scala, playframework

following the [play websockets example](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWebSockets) i run into a weird problem.

the following example from the docs is working:

```
  Future.successful(request.session.get("user") match {
    case None => Left(Forbidden)
    case Some(_) => Right(out => ChannelActor.props(out, "", ""))
  })
```

to understand the code I tried to play around with the code:

```
  Future.successful({
    val test = request.session.get("user") match {
      case None => Left(Forbidden)
      case Some(_) => Right(out => ChannelActor.props(out, "", ""))
    }
    test
  })
```

the compiler complains, that there is a "missing parameter type" for the value `out`.

Why is that? I just added the saved the Either in test and returned this val instead of the match statement itself.

thanks

Comment: Likely the scala compiler can't infer the type of `test` base on what you have, but I'm unable to reproduce your exact example because it's quite different than what's in the Play docs.

Comment: I copied the example from the "Rejecting a WebSocket" section within the link i included. the only difference is, that I included the out value as the example in "Handling WebSockets with actors" shows

Comment: Still compiles for me. Are you doing: `WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[String, String] { request => out =>` ... ? That's the only way I can make it fail.

Comment: i think the compiler just did not know whats in "Right" - just got it working with:      Future.successful({

        val handler: play.api.mvc.WebSocket.HandlerProps = {
          out =>
            ChannelActor.props(out, "", "")
        }
        val test = request.session.get("user") match {
          case None => Left(Forbidden)
          case Some(_) => Right(handler)
        }
        test
      })

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that you have to write `Right(out => [...]`, which is not actually in the documentation and therefore the example there does not work (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.3/ScalaWebSockets).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the Scala compiler cannot infer the type of `out`. You never tell the compiler (or reader) what type `out` actually is. You can see that it is a functions returns type `Props`, but what type if its input is is never specified. Therefore, the type information you can derive from this code is just `Future[Either[Result, ??? => Props]`.

You solved this by annotating this handler function `val handler: HandlerProps` which is an alias for `val handler: ActorRef => Props`. So by annotating it with type information, you supplied the Scala compiler with enough type information to compile this. You can also do this by writing `Right(out: ActorRef => ChannelActor.props(out, "", ""))`, or writing `val test: Either[Result, HandlerProps] = ... match {`.