# missing parameter type in lambda

Tags: scala, types, lambda

I have the following in a worksheet:

```
val tarr = Array((1, Some(1.0)), (2, Some(6.0)))
val r1 = tarr exists Function.tupled((_, sf: Option[Double]) => sf == None)
```

The IDE complays with `missing parameter type` for the `_` but the worksheet spits out the desired result.

If I plug the same line of code in a package and compile, the compilation stops with, again, `missing parameter type` for both `_` and `sf`

I am a bit [confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233760/missing-parameter-type-for-simple-expression) on why I need to specify the type there and why the worksheet works and the compilation no.

Answer (score 0):

In my eclipse IDE, the code works fine

```
object yrd {
val tarr = Array((1, Some(1.0)), (2, Some(6.0)))

                                              //> tarr  : Array[(Int, Some[Double])] = Array((1,Some(1.0)), (2,Some(6.0)))
```

val r1 = tarr exists Function.tupled((_, sf: Option[Double]) => sf == None)
                                                  //> r1  : Boolean = false

}